# Use of abstract classes, interface and List in C#

Tags: c#, interface, abstract

I have the following code sections and I am trying to implement a method that returns a list. My structure is as follows : abstract class "Coordinates" -> public class "YCoordinate" with my interface pointing to "YCoordinate". I don't want my interface directly chatting to my abstract class as I feel the implementations of my abstract class is responsible for work.

Interface :

```
interface IYCoordinate
{
    System.Collections.Generic.List<Coordinates> GetYCoordinateList();
}
```

Abstract class :

```
public abstract class Coordinates
{
    private int coordinatePriority;
    private int coordinate;

    public Coordinates(int CoordinatePriority, int Coordinate)
    {
        this.CoordinatePriority = CoordinatePriority;
        this.Coordinate = Coordinate;
    }

    public Coordinates() { }
    public int CoordinatePriority { get { return coordinatePriority; } set { coordinatePriority = value; } }
    public int Coordinate { get { return coordinate; } set { coordinate = value; } }

    public virtual List<Coordinates> GetYCoordinateList()
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Implementation of Interface and abstract class (this is the part that breaks):

```
public class YCoordinate : Coordinates, IYCoordinate
{
    public override List<Coordinates> GetYCoordinateList() 
    {
        List<Coordinates> _list = new List<Coordinates>();
        _list.Add(new IYCoordinate(1, 5000));
        _list.Add(new IYCoordinate(2, 100000));
        return _list;
    }
}
```

However, I am trying to return a list of Coordinates and getting stuck on the public override function in the "YCoordinate" class as I cannot instantiate the Coordinates class directly (because its abstract).  How can I return a list of Coordinates?  The same error happens if I put in IYCoordinate as shown above.

Maybe my implementation is completely wrong? Any recommendation for doing it better would be welcome.

Later on there will be XCoordinate class and so on. If this approach seems like a bit much its because I am trying to get the hang of the theory behind this.

Comment: `IYCoordinate.GetYCoordinateList()` should return `IList<Coordinates>`, not `List<Coordinates>`.

Comment: @cdhowie it is not required by the compiler to return an interface as a return result of a method defined in an interface. For design and architecture reasons you may choose to do so, however, the definition of the interface as written by the OP is not the issue here. IMO the YCoordinate class is flawed in that it owns a list of itself. This would be better owned by another class. The example by the OP is somewhat confusing.

Comment: @CodeMonkeyKing I never said that the compiler would complain.  My comment was intended to instill good design practices, not point out an error.

Comment: @cdhowie it seems like a commandment and not a design "best practice". It's not a necessity. The problems with the code posted are far deeper than changing to the IList<> interface.

Comment: @CodeMonkeyKing The problems are in fact unrelated, which is why I posted a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: @cdhowie no worries :)

Comment: Thank you, apologies on the confusing list portion that owns a list of itself. To get it to work I pasted the wrong list in. I've also made sure now that I am using IList instead of List.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

1) you have one interface - `IYCoordinate`, but you are saying you will want to have `IXCoordinate` and `IZCoordinate` too. Just use single interface - `ICoordinate` and one function - `GetCoordinateList`:

```
interface ICoordinate
{
    IList<Coordinates> GetCoordinateList();
}
```

Actually, this intefrace can be eliminated if you are using my approach

2) in your abstract class you will have a stub for `GetCoordinateList` which does nothing

```
public abstract class Coordinates: ICoordinate
{
    public virtual List<Coordinates> GetCoordinateList()
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Actually you can eliminate `ICoordinate` interface altogether and use only abstract class. It's ffine.

3) You will derive one(or more than one) classes from that `Coordinates` class and implement `GetCoordinate` as you like

```
public class YCoordinate : Coordinates
{
    public override List<Coordinates> GetCoordinateList() 
    {
        List<Coordinates> _list = new List<Coordinates>();
        _list.Add(new YCoordinate(1, 5000));
        _list.Add(new YCoordinate(2, 100000));
        return _list;
    }
}
```

Thus you are having one single interface and one single function name to get coordinates from any class derived from `Coordinates`. If you will add `XCoordinate` class in future you will need to implement the same function with the same name.
And when you will be instantiating `XCoordinate` or `YCoordinate` or `WhateverCoordinate` class you will always know there is a `GetCoordinateList` function that you need

```
var coordClass = new XCoordinate();
coordClass.GetCoordinateList();
```

Moreover, when passing something that has to have `GetCoordinateList` member you can use your interface `ICoordinate` or abstract class Coordinates wherever you like.

Comment: In the interface you say IList, I just changed that too list since it was complaining about it.  Thought I could have kept IList and change the function in the abstract class and so on.  However I am still confused by step nr 3.  You say new List<Coordinates> but then talk about YCoordinates in the next line?  If I leave it as YCoordinates it complains that there is no constructor for for the two arguments. I cannot change it to Coordinates, since its abstract.

Comment: I moved all the constructors from the abstract class down to YCoordinate instead and now its working.  I was hoping however not to have typed with each implementation of the class but then I am having my concrete class now as advised before.

Comment: @Sonja, you can have a constructor in the abstract class (Coordinates) and you have to call this from your constructor in your derived class (YCoordinate). I'll post it in an answer because it's more readable.

Comment: Well if you need to pass those 2 parameters to the base constructor(Coordinates class) there is nothing we can do here - this is how C# language is designed and there is no other option for base class to know those parameters if you don't pass them through. If you don't need those 2 parameters you can just invoke base class' constructor without any parameters.

Answer (score 0):

On these lines:

```
_list.Add(new IYCoordinate(1, 5000));
_list.Add(new IYCoordinate(2, 100000));
```

You need to instantiate an object of a class that derives from the `Coordinates` class.  Here you are trying to create a new instance of an interface, and you cannot do that -- interface members have no definition!

Create a subclass of `Coordinates` and instantiate that instead.  (Or remove the `abstract` keyword from the definition of this class -- it's not clear why it is abstract anyway, as there are no abstract members.)

Comment: Tx... I missed changed the method in the abstract class to public abstract List<Coordinates> GetYCoordinateList(); Will try and look at your other suggestion now.

Comment: It looks like you want to create an instance of `YCoordinate`, so try `new YCoordinate` instead of `new YICoordinate`.

Answer (score 0):

You need at least one concrete class.

At the moment you only have abstract classes and interfaces.

Comment: I understand now, busy looking at the recommendation from cdhowie below

Answer (score 0):

the simple answer....change these two lines:

```
    _list.Add(new IYCoordinate(1, 5000));
    _list.Add(new IYCoordinate(2, 100000));
```

to this:

```
    _list.Add(new YCoordinate(1, 5000));
    _list.Add(new YCoordinate(2, 100000));
```

note that im creating the class there, not the interface.

Long answer...Blablablaster got that one right :-)

Answer (score 0):

- Starting from Blablablaster answer -
  In my opinion, you don't need an interface here.

  public abstract class Coordinates
  {
      public int CoordinatePriority { get; set; }
      public int Coordinate { get; set; }

  ```
  protected Coordinates(int CoordinatePriority, int Coordinate)
  {
      this.CoordinatePriority = CoordinatePriority;
      this.Coordinate = Coordinate;
  }

  public abstract List<Coordinates> GetCoordinateList();
  ```

  }

As you've noticed I've created an abstract method instead of the method in the interface.
Every derived class must implement this method.

```
class YCoordinate:Coordinates
{
    public YCoordinate(int CoordinatePriority, int Coordinate) : 
        base(CoordinatePriority, Coordinate) //Call constructor of baseclass
    {
    }

    public override List<Coordinates> GetCoordinateList()
    {
        List<Coordinates> list = new List<Coordinates>();
        list.Add(new YCoordinate(1, 5000));
        list.Add(new YCoordinate(2, 100000));
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this,  I am going to play around with this now.  Reason being for using interfaces is because I am learning how to implement interfaces and abstracts properly, but I understand its not always necessary to use both of them or at all depending on the scenario.